# Unexpected end of form when uploading to express server, Multer

Tags: multer

This question has been asked, the solutions offered were to use body-parser and downgrade Multer to 1.4.3 (which seems like it's not a real solution).

I'm attempting to upload a file using Fetch.
My code is:

```
   const file = fs.createReadStream(`${desktopDir}/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg`);
    const title = "Test";

const form = new FormData();

form.append("title", title);
form.append("file", file);

    const response = await fetch('https://example.com/uploads/1234', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu",
          },
      body: form });
    const responseData = await response.json();
```

Notice I used boundary. If I don't use boundary I get an error.
The boundary here is just something I got off line so I assume, this can also be the reason for the error.

On the express server side I have:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: '/var/www/vhosts/preview.inkto.art/httpdocs/html/' });

router.post('/uploads/:id', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  const title = req.body.title;
  res.json({ msg: `file ${title} uploaded successfully!` });
});
```

The request header returned from the server:

```
:method: POST
:path: /uploads/1234
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 17
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu
origin: file://
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the correct boundary in my headers:

```
 headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
      },
```

Where form is
const form = new FormData();

```
    form.append("title", title);
    form.append("file", file);
```